# How do I override / add to the method_missing while maintaining searchlogic functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to add some behavior to my model when `method_missing` is thrown, but I know searchlogic already uses that for their named search scopes.

What is the proper way to extend `method_missing` functionality? Is there a way to react to a `method_missing` trigger? Much like how one would bind functions to events in javascript?

Answer (score 9):

when you say you want something to happen when method missing is thrown, do you mean every time or just when search logic didn't find something? The former is quite simple:

```
def method_missing(name, *)
  if name =~ /foo/i
    # call your custom method
    # or for example define_method
  else
    # you do not want to handle the
    # method, so fall back to standard behavior
    super
  end
end
```

Where you replace `name =~ /foo/i` with a condition that checks whether you want to handle the missing method or not. The latter is not as easy. I can't answer it, because i do not know search logic, but you'd have to check whether search logic found something or not before calling your custom method.